# How do I create Singleton instance for a library referenced from nuget

Tags: c#, singleton

Task is to call a third party service/wrapper multiple times and get the response. Below is the sample code and I am trying to figured out how to create singleton instance for the service.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> trips = new List<string>();
        trips.Add("ABC");
        trips.Add("XYZ");
        foreach (string s in trips) {
            Test.TestMethod(s);
        }
    }
}

public static class Test
{
    public static bool TestMethod(string trip)
    {
        BridgeApiClient bridgeApiClient = new BridgeApiClient("http://localhost/Service.svc", "username", "password");
        TripRequest tr = new TripRequest();
        tr.TripNumber = trip;

        var response = bridgeApiClient.GetTrip(tr);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your post and actually ask a question, so we can help you better!

Comment: Add this to the `Test` class:  `private static readonly BridgeApiClient bridgeApiClient = new BridgeApiClient("http://localhost/Service.svc", "username", "password");`

Comment: @BogdanDoicin edited. please check.

Comment: @Zer0 Do you think defining class as static is best option?

Answer (score 1):

You can just declare a `static` member variable and use that:

```
public static class Test
{
    private static readonly BridgeApiClient bridgeApiClient = new BridgeApiClient("http://localhost/Service.svc", "username", "password");

    public static bool TestMethod(string trip)
    {
        TripRequest tr = new TripRequest();
        tr.TripNumber = trip;
        var response = bridgeApiClient.GetTrip(tr);
        return true;
    }
}
```